Standalone Boost.Asio + Boost.Beast
I am learning boost and want to make a http server using Beast and Asio, but i don't want to drag the whole boost library within my project.
What i did so far: added Boost.Beast and Boost.Asio as submodules from github repos, include them into my project and define BOOST_ASIO_STANDALONE.
Of course it doesn't build and missing a lot of files.
So my question is: can it be done? what parts of boost must be included to make this work?

You almost certainly need lots of others parts as you found out. Clone the whole thing and see what happens. Interested to see if someone has a better suggestion.

Beast does not have a standalone mode: you need boost. As with any boost library you can try to excise the subset using the BCP tool.
However, depending on the task you will end up dragging in a lot of dependencies. The only positive part here is that Beast is header-only, so any savings actually reduce the size of the dependency.
I'd suggest BCP is rarely worth it, except for very isolated things. Say, if you want to have just boost::container::flat_map or just boost::core::string_view.
